# Apply function to manipulate Python Pandas DataFrame group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have data in a pandas DataFrame that requires considerable clean up with functions applied to the DataFrame's 'ID' groups. How does one apply any arbitrary function to manipulate Pandas DataFrame groups? A simplified example of the DataFrame is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

waypoint_time_string = ['0.5&3.0&6.0' for x in range(10)]
moving_string = ['0 0 0&0 0.1 0&1 1 1.2' for x in range(10)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2], 'time':[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5],
         'X':[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],'Y':[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],'Z':[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
         'waypoint_times':waypoint_time_string,
         'moving':moving_string})
```

I would like to apply the function `set_group_positions` (defined below) to each 'ID' group of `df`. I have only been successful looping through the DataFrame. It seems that there must be a more 'Pandas.groupby' way of doing this. Here is an example of my implementation that I'm looking to replace:

```
sub_frames = [] 
unique_IDs = df['ID'].unique()
for unique_ID in unique_IDs:
    working_df = df.loc[df['ID']==unique_ID]
    working_df = set_group_positions(working_df)
    sub_frames.append(working_df)

final_df = pd.concat(sub_frames)
```

And to complete a working example, here are additional helper functions:

```
def set_x_vel(row):
    return(row['X'] + row['x_movement'])
def set_y_vel(row):
    return(row['Y'] + row['y_movement'])
def set_z_vel(row):
    return(row['Z'] + row['z_movement'])

output_time_list = df['time'].unique().tolist()

#main function to apply to each ID group in the data frame:
def set_group_positions(df): #pass the combined df here
    working_df = df
    times_string = working_df['waypoint_times'].iloc[0]
    times_list = times_string.split('&')
    times_list = [float(x) for x in times_list]
    points_string = working_df['moving']
    points_string = points_string.iloc[0]
    points_list = points_string.split('&')
    points_x = []
    points_y = []
    points_z = []
    for point in points_list:
        point_list = point.split(' ')
        points_x.append(point_list[0])
        points_y.append(point_list[1])
        points_z.append(point_list[2])

    #get corresponding positions for HPAC times,
    #since there could be mismatches

    points_x = np.cumsum([float(x) for x in points_x])
    points_y = np.cumsum([float(x) for x in points_x])
    points_z = np.cumsum([float(x) for x in points_x])

    x_interp = np.interp(output_time_list,times_list,points_x).tolist()
    y_interp = np.interp(output_time_list,times_list,points_y).tolist()
    z_interp = np.interp(output_time_list,times_list,points_z).tolist()

    working_df.loc[:,('x_movement')] = x_interp
    working_df.loc[:,('y_movement')] = y_interp
    working_df.loc[:,('z_movement')] = z_interp

    working_df.loc[:,'x_pos'] = working_df.apply(set_x_vel, axis = 1)
    working_df.loc[:,'y_pos'] = working_df.apply(set_y_vel, axis = 1)
    working_df.loc[:,'z_pos'] = working_df.apply(set_z_vel, axis = 1)

    return(working_df)
```

While my current implementation works, on my real data set, it takes about 20 minutes for me to run, where a simple groupby.apply lambda call on my DataFrame takes only seconds to a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping, you can use `apply` with `groupby` and a function call:

```
df = df.groupby('ID').apply(set_group_positions)
```

Comment: Doh...could've sworn this was the first thing I tried :) Thank you.

Comment: No problem!  Glad I could help.